# Prove that every tree with at least 1 edge has at least 2 leaves

Tags: discrete-mathematics

This is what I have so far and would appreciate any problems with it.
(recall that a leaf is a vertex of degree 1).

a tree with n vertices has n - 1 edges. Assuming one leaf we use the handshake theorem we have:

= 2(n-1) = 2n - 2
Since every vertex has degree at least 2 except the one leaf we get
2 Handshake theorem >= 2(2(n-1)+1) = 4n - 2 > 2(n-1) and we find a contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is fine (assuming the used ingredients are available).

Alternatively, one might try the following idea for a "direct" (but probably inferior) proof: Assume $ab$ is an edge. Then you can "walk away from $b$" starting at $a$ until you have to stop at a leaf (possibly already at $a$). Likewise, you can walk away from $a$ starting from $b$ until you have to stop and find a leaf. The leaves found this way are different.

Comment: Or, take a longest path and show that both ends are leaves.